# How does Tag usage change over time?

Tags: discussion, fun

This question really belongs in meta.tex.stackexchange, but I just created an account and don't have enough rep to post there.

I used the June 2013 Stack Exchange data dump to look at the time series (by month) of the 5 most popular tags on tex.stackexchange.  Here's a plot:

[image: Count of top 5 tags on TeX.SE over time]

Interpretation is left to the reader.

This is more of a fun fact than a question (sorry about that), although I'd certainly like to hear any thoughts on other fun facts that could be had from this data.

Comment: tikz/PGF for the win!

Comment: @Jubobs Maybe it's winning as a tag because it causes the most problems ;) You have more [tag:biblatex] questions than [tag:bibtex] questions, and still, I'm quite convinced that more people use BibTeX than biblatex ;)

Comment: @tohecz You may be right!

Comment: Alex, how difficult was it to produce the plot? I would be for instance very insterested in the comparison of [tag:graphics], [tag:tikz-pgf] and [tag:pstricks]. Thanks!

Comment: I can see that usage is trending upwards over time, but why does it zigzag like that?